# responsive css menu > ul height fix

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

I'm novise in responsive css/html.
I try to implement the css-only responsive navigation and I got a problem.

See the code: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fp9px17L/)

In menu, our services > distribution overlaps the next menu item.
adding the `overflow:hidden` in `#dropdown ul li ul` fix this problem in firefox, but, in IE and mobile browser it does not work.

Please help me to solve this.

Regards, Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested `li` is inheriting the following styles from its parent;

```
#dropdown ul li { height:50px;}
```

You you remove the height, the overlap will be prevented.